# External HD partition table destroyed

Tags: hard-drive

I was trying to create bootable USB media in Boot Camp Assistant. Had a small USB plugged in and my HDD. Upon formatting I think my partition table screwed up. I had 2 partitions. 1.2TB NTFS and 0.8TB exFAT. Immediately I ran diskutil and gpt which show:

```
$ gpt show
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1          62
          63  2344529857      1  MBR Part 7
  2344529920  1562497024      2  MBR Part 7
  3907026944        2220
```

diskutil (I already tried to fix using gpt add - causing both partitions to read NTFS):

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                   TYPE NAME               SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0: FDisk_partition_scheme                   *2.0 TB    disk1
   1:           Windows_NTFS                    1.2 TB    disk1s1
   1:           Windows_NTFS                    800.0 GB  disk1s2
```

I tried to recover it using gpt add and made the GUID NTFS for both. They wouldnt mount.

[image: GPT ADD]

I then tried pdisk and completely ruined my partition table.

[image: PDISK]

Is there a way i can get my partitions back? After pdisk my gpt show now reads:

```
$ gpt show
       start         size  index  contents
           0   3907029164
```

and diskutil reads:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                   TYPE NAME               SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:                                          *2.0 TB    disk2
```

Am I screwed? I havent written to the HD. I know my files and partitions are still there. I just need help fixing this.

(p.s. currently using testdisk and scanning as an INTEL drive).

Comment: In the first three screenshots you are maltreating disk1, in the last three disk2! ??? Also, pdisk is a tool to partition disks with the [Apple Partition Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map) scheme which is rather old (and inappropriate here)! The proper tool for MBR disks is fdisk.

Comment: yeah it changed disk number during all my mucking about which was strange. Testdisk quick scan couldnt find the parts so doing deeper scan. Im now preparing for the worst.

Comment: If you provide/allow remote access i may have look. Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309948/93229 another: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309863/cant-see-external-hdd-partition-in-disk-utility

Comment: That sounds great. how do i allow remote access?

Comment: You have to download TeamViewer (currently TV 12 is installed here - AFAIK the latest version TV 13 doesn't allow access for TV 12 clients - so you have to download, install and configure an older version https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/previous-versions/). Root access and a tool (e.g. wxHexEditor) are required in your environment. The TeamViewer credentials have to be sent to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.

Comment: hey klanomath. I had trouble installing wxHexEditor. I installed another tool. HexFiend.

Comment: I recommend to download and install an older version of wxHexEditor (the latest seems to be buggy). Usually I transfer the zip (of the older version) to the remote client because it's not possible to d/l it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is about data loss on a windows-formatted disk, you might want to ask in a windows-centric place. It sounds to me like data recovery (deleted file scans) would be your only hope.

I'm not clear, did you have a USB thumb drive and a 2 TB USB HDD plugged in, and picked the wrong one for making the Bootcamp tools?

Comment: The reason for my initial posting here was that I am using osx and it is an issue I need resolved using osx.

I had a somewhat similar issue before where my partition table of my mac hdd had corrupted and was fixed manually using gpt.

To answer storage media, I'm using a 2TB HDD formatted in paragon partition manager. 1 NTFS part and 1 exFAT part. I had ALSO plugged in a thumb drive to create a bootable media using bootcamp assistant. I had selected the right USB to create the bootable media, however, ALL USB devices freaked out and my HDD was left corrupted.

Comment: Data recovery might be my best option, however i know that my info is still there and perfectly in tact, I Just need to find the right sectors and rebuild the drive partition map.

Comment: You have the partition information. Have you tried using `fdisk` to reenter the MBR partition values?

Comment: I will do that. Just dont know the commands to do it.

Comment: Could I get some assistance please? THANKS! :)